# How can I upload a PDF file to a SharePoint site?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

How can I upload a PDF file to a SharePoint site using Python requests? This is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

sessionObj = requests.session()
url1 = 'https://globalconsumer.collaborationtools.consumer.citigroup.net/sites'
sessionObj.auth = ('username', 'password')

r = sessionObj.post(url1, auth=sessionObj.auth, verify=False)

print("LOGIN RESPONSE: " + format(r.status_code))
print(r.url)
```

Comment: You're not actually including any file data in your request. Have you seen the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)?

Comment: import requests
import os
import sys
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

filename = 'C:\\Users\\nk77527\\Desktop\\AIXtoLinux Migration.xlsx'

verify = 'C:\\Citi\\PythonPrograms\\UdemyPython\cert.cer'
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('NAM\\nk77527','Warren217', session)

file = open(filename, 'rb')
bytes = bytearray(file.read())
resp = requests.put('http://globalconsumer.collaborationtools.consumer.citigroup.net/u002fsites/u002fCBOL-AO/u002f_layouts/u002fUpload.aspx' + filename, data=bytes, auth=session.auth, verify=False)

print(resp.status_code)